# Computer power-on issues

Tags: windows-10, desktop-computer

I've just joined this site to try and find some advice about my computer not powering on.

I use windows 10 - I'll try and find any specs you'll need but please note that I am not the most knowledgeable about computers!

I had been using it normally today and everything was working fine. I shut it down, and about one hour later I went to start it up again.
On pressing the power button, the computer made noise and fans started going like normal. However, after a couple of seconds the computer turned itself off again, and then turned itself on.
At this point, there is no output to my screen at all, and the Hard disk drive is not flashing.

I manually turned the power off and disconnected all unnecessary hardware. I pressed the power button again, and the cycle as previously described repeated.

So that is where I am stuck now!

It would be great if you could give advice on what the problem may be.

If you have any questions please let me know.

Thank you!

-Brad

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a bad power supply.

If any other component failed, the PC would typically at least stay on for long enough to attemp to boot.

Try to swap out the power supply with another one.